# Overlays with beamer: \includegraphics<...> causes figures to shift

Tags: beamer, graphics, overlays

I have noticed something strange when using overlays with figures in beamer. Whenever I use overlays with more than two figures (of exactly the same size), then each consecutive figure shifts a bit to the right, except for the last two.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{center} %
        \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{example-image} %
        \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{example-image} %
        \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{example-image} %
    \end{center} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Figure B will be shifted slightly right compared to figure A. However, figures B and C are on the exact same spot.

How do I ensure that all of them are on the same spot?

Comment: `%` end of lines to stop adding spaces

Comment: That didn't change anything for me

Comment: (please make a complete test file that shows the problem, you can use `example-image` as the image, it is available for tests, otherwise impossible to guess.

Comment: you still have spaces between each of the images.  Remove (or comment out) the white space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
        \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{example-image} %
        \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{example-image} %
        \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{example-image} %
```

is equivalent to

```
        \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{example-image} \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{example-image} \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{example-image} %
```

so the second image is one space to the right and the third image is two spaces to the right of the position of the first image.

You want

```
        \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{example-image}%
        \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{example-image}%
        \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{example-image}%
```

which is like

```
        \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{example-image}\includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{example-image}\includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{example-image}
```

There is nothing special about beamer or images here compare

```
A %
B %
C %
```

which typesets as A B C

and

```
A%
B%
C%
```

which typesets as ABC

Comment: Thanks for that! 
I can't believe I didn't notice that I had left those spaces. I looked at this for an hour I just couldn't figure out what was going on.